# PowerShell Print this business weeks mon-fri

Tags: powershell

I would like Powershell to determine the current week & print monday - friday in the format:

```
mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy
```

I saw a way to get the day of the week which is nice but I would like to just have it show the dates.

What I have so far, it works but if I run any day but Monday the dates would be off:

```
$bar = "------------------------------------"
$today = (Get-Date)
$dates = @($today.AddDays(0).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'),
$today.AddDays(1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'),
$today.AddDays(2).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'),
$today.AddDays(3).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'),
$today.AddDays(4).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))

$result = "`n{0}`n{1}`n`n`n{2}`n{3}`n`n`n{4}`n{5}`n`n`n{6}`n{7}`n`n`n{8}`n{9}`n" -f $dates[0], $bar, $dates[1], $bar, $dates[2], $bar, $dates[3], $bar, $dates[4], $bar

echo $result
```

Comment: consider: `$day=get-date; while($day.DayOfWeek -ne 'Monday') {$day=$day.AddDays(-1) }; $day`

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do what you want. [*grin*] it uses the builtin weekday list, indexes into that with the current weekday name, calculates the 1st day of the current week, generates an array of dates for the current week, and finally prints it out with the lines & vertical spacing that you seem to want.

```
# for my locale, the 1st day is "Sunday"
$WeekDayList = [System.DayOfWeek].GetEnumNames()
$Line = '-' * 40
$Newline = [environment]::NewLine
$BlankLineCount = 3

# the ".Date" property gives you midnite, not "now"
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$TodayNumber = $WeekDayList.IndexOf($Today.DayOfWeek.ToString())
$WeekStartDate = $Today.AddDays(-$TodayNumber)

$CurrentWeek = foreach ($Offset in 0..6)
    {
    $WeekStartDate.AddDays($Offset).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    }

-join ($CurrentWeek -join "$Newline$Line$($Newline * $BlankLineCount)"), "$Line$($Newline * $BlankLineCount)"
```

output ...

```
2019-01-20
----------------------------------------


2019-01-21
----------------------------------------


2019-01-22
----------------------------------------


2019-01-23
----------------------------------------


2019-01-24
----------------------------------------


2019-01-25
----------------------------------------


2019-01-26
----------------------------------------


[not part of the output - needed to show that there are two blank lines above this one. [*grin*]
```

Comment: Thanks for including this in the post, it is a better improvement on what I currently have been doing.

Comment: @riceIT6 - you are most welcome! glad to have helped - and to provide an interesting alternative. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the requirement to get a date from a week day, and wrote a function to return a `[DateTime]`.

Using this function and `ToString()` to format the date to your requirements, gives an output of:

```
2019/01/21 - 2019/01/25
```

Code:

```
Function Get-DateFromDay {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')]
        [string]$WeekDay,

        [Int]$AddWeeks = 0
    )

    $DayNumber = @{
        'Saturday'  = 1; 
        'Sunday'    = 0; 
        'Monday'    = -1;
        'Tuesday'   = -2; 
        'Wednesday' = -3;
        'Thursday'  = -4
        'Friday'    = -5
    }

    [System.Datetime]$Today = Get-Date
    $NumDaysSinceDateFromDay = $Today.DayOfWeek.value__ + $DayNumber[$WeekDay]

    [System.Datetime]$DateFromDayThisWeek = $Today.AddDays(-$NumDaysSinceDateFromDay)
    $DateFromDayThisWeek.AddDays( + ($AddWeeks * 7))
}


$Monday = (Get-DateFromDay -WeekDay Monday).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
$Friday = (Get-DateFromDay -WeekDay Friday).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')

Write-Output "$Monday - $Friday"
```

---

And a few examples of use for those who come across this post in the future:

Thursday next week:

```
Get-DateFromDay -WeekDay Thursday -AddWeeks 1
```

Tuesday last week:

```
Get-DateFromDay -WeekDay Tuesday -AddWeeks -1
```

Comment: Yip, this is what I was looking for. Thank you James C.!

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).